# Como puedo generar una barra de progreso mientras se genera un ZIP con php

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Estoy generando un archivo zip con PHP este zip lo genero por medio de un boton en mi html de la siguiente manera

HTML

```
<button class="btn btn-success btndowloadO">
Descargar archivos
 </button>
```

Por medio de Jquery con el evento click realizo la acción de redirigir a un php de la siguiente manera

```
 $('.btndowloadO').click(function(event) {
  location.href = 'downloadattachments.php;
 });
```

El PHP a donde redirige es el que se encarga de generar el ZIP de varios archivos dejo el codigo de
downloadattachments.php

```
$rutaDowlod = "../anexos";



    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    $filename = "mi.zip";

    
    $rootPath = realpath($rutaDowlod);


    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);


    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );

    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
    
        if (!$file->isDir()) {
        
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

            
            $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
        }
    }


    
    $zip->close();

    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename . "");
    readfile($filename);
    unlink($filename);
```

Me genera sin problemas mi zip pero lo que quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar es como hacer que en lo que genere el zip pueda hacer que aparezca una imagen de cargando o generando mientras se esta construyendo el ZIP ya que que cuando el ZIP es grande pies tarda en generarse y queiro hacerle saber al usuario que se esta generando

De antemano agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Mi idea sería hacer un proceso que se ejecute en línea de comando, como en un hilo independiente en background, el proceso de creación del ZIP, y que a cada rato se este preguntando por AJAX a ese proceso en que estatus está.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí tienes varias soluciones y varios problemas
en el evento click()

```
<script>
    $('.btndowloadO').click(function(event) {
    
      // Annades una acción de load antes del location
      $('.loader').fadeIn();  // Esto te hara mostrar el cargador
    
      // Loader podría ser el div donde esta tu barra de progreso
    
    
      location.href = 'downloadattachments.php;
    });
</script>
```

Aquí esta como mostrar barras de progreso en Bootstrap
[https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/bootstrap-3/capitulo-6/barras-de-progreso]

El problema radica en barios lugares lo primero es que deberías traer el Zip por Ajax y no por un href del navegador, lo segundo es que no tendrás el load exacto por el tema de quien hace el trabajo es la librería de PHP, por tanto en el caso que quieras el loadbar exacto en tiempo real necesitas que el script que construyas en el php obtenga a cada milisegundo el porcentaje del proceso de creación del zip y después lo devuelva como un json a un websocket que estés corriendo para que desde el navegador lo tengas en tiempo real para poder mostrárselo al usuario.

Lo otro y menos complejo seria en lugar de un websocket usar Ajax a cada segundo para que te devuelva el porciento de trabajo del zip o del tipo de compresión que estés realizando, y mostrarlo al cliente a cada segundo, eso haría un efecto de carga bastante bueno, todo depende de que tanto trabajes en que quede lo mas a tiempo real posible.

Mi recomendación usa esta ultima con Ajax e investiga como la librería que estas usando podría mostrarte que tanto a comprimido del fichero o ficheros, por ejemplo seria algo como total: 13000000 bites, comprimidos 4500000 bites, usas una relación de porciento y de ahi se lo muestras al usuario en una progressbar.